# How to stack photos and sending them after refreshing the internet connection?

Tags: android

How to stack photo on Android and sending them after renew internet connection.?
 have an application that takes pictures and sends them to the server.
What to do if there is no connection to the server.? I got the requirement for a project to stack photo on phone and sent them immediately after internet connection renew.

Please help anybody cause i don't have any idea for it.

Comment: Provide more details... which program.. what script, what OS you're running. **Hint**: *I have an application that does magic* sounds a little vague. **server..server.... I'm a server... not serving you due to lack of information**... get it?!

Comment: The application takes pictures, adds a GPS location, and then calculates the distance to the destination from the photo. After this photo is sent to the ftp server. And the problem is what to do when you do not have an internet connection. The application must store photos and send them when the internet connection returns.

Comment: Without names of programs, etc... your question becomes garbage collected due to downvoting. You are describing a `black box` at the moment with too many variables. Be specific or get downvoted and question removed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is  save the photo locally in case you can't send it immediately. To archieve that, you can create a local sqlite database and save the photo. This steep is a little bit tricky, but you can follow [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20180125184745/http://whats-online.info/science-and-tutorials/129/how-to-store-images-in-SQLite-database-in-Android-and-display-in-listview/) to get an idea of how to do that.

The next step is to listen when the smartphone gets conection to internet. This can be done with a BroadcastReceiver. here i show you how.

in the manifest

.....

```
 <application
        android:name=".aplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
...
<receiver android:name=".ConectivityChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
...
</application>
```

And next you implemente your broadcastReceiver

```
public class ConectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
if (isConnected(context)) {
//if have conection to internet send the photo
}

}

public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

And that is, good luck :D